# Ruby 1.9.3: import all files in a given directory

Tags: ruby

I am having trouble import all of the .rb files I need from a given directory, I know this question has been asked a lot but none of the earlier posts seem to solve my problem.

Here is my directory structure:

```
- Docs
- Lexer
- Parser
  --> Parser.rb
- SyntaxTree
  --> I want all the .rb files from here
  --> Sets.rb (Module I want to import)
      --> EMPTY_SET (constant I want to reference)
- Test
<Main Program>
```

I am currently working in Parser.rb and I need to get all of the .rb files from the SyntaxTree directory so I can reference them inside of Parser.rb. I also want to import the Sets module that is contained in Sets.rb.

Here is my current way of trying to import all of the ruby files that I saw in most of the previous posts:

```
Dir['../SyntaxTree/*.rb'].each {|file| require file}
```

I also tried:

```
Dir['../SyntaxTree/*.rb'].each {|file| require_relative file}
```

With either of these method I still get errors when trying to include the Sets module:

```
class Parser
  include Sets
  .
  .
end
`<class:Parser>': uninitialized constant Parser::Sets (NameError)
```

If I directly include `Sets.rb` the error goes away

Any ideas would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best approach is to set up proper `autoload` dependencies within your modules so that the required classes are loaded on demand. If you simply load all of the files in using `require`, it won't be obvious which order they have to be loaded based on filenames and any inter-dependenceies are not resolved.

This is why having a top-level namespace for your application can help. Example:

```
module MyApp
  autoload(:Parser, 'my_app/parser')
  autoload(:Sets, 'my_app/sets')
end
```

Now those classes should load automatically on-demand.

Comment: ok, but this is only useful for the top level imports right? Parser.rb isn't at the top level, could I do something similar inside of Parser.rb?

Comment: Yes, each module lists the submodules and classes it manages in its own namespace.

Comment: but there are a lot of classes in my SyntaxTree/ folder that I want to load, wouldn't I have to make an entry for each one?>

Comment: It's a bit of a hassle if you have an existing project you're trying to augment but usually no big deal if you do it as you go. Adding an `autoload` line is usually inconsequential compared to implementing that additional class or module.